# parallelism in "not only but also"

Tags: parallelism

Is the following usage of "not only but also" correct? I mean in terms of parallelism.

> For instance, Azadi Tower in Tehran not only is aesthetically pleasing
> but also is a cultural identity.

Comment: Better to write "...is not only X but also Y".

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298957/is-not-only-but-also-used-correctly-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**is** occurs in both parallels: you could just remove it from both and insert it after "Tehran". It also sounds nicer to have **is** before **not**.

> For instance, Azadi Tower in Tehran is not only aesthetically pleasing but also a cultural identity.

I would only put a main verb within the parallel part if I wanted to use a different verb in each part, for example:

> This jacket not only **looks** good, but also **feels** comfortable.

I am not convinced that a tower can be  "a cultural identity". maybe "a symbol of [our] cultural identity"?

Comment: A cultural icon, I'd say...