# "not only....but (also)" or "not....but"?

Tags: sentence-construction

"Soft skills are skills that apply not only to one specific job but are universal."
I think this sentence is correct and it means that soft skills are not limited to one specific job but have universal applicability.
But someone said that the sentence is wrong and it should be "Soft skills are skills that not only apply to one specific job but are universal.".
I searched questions about "not only but", but I'm still not sure how it works in this specific sentence.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. It’s expected here that one do some work on one’s own before asking a question. At least by seeing whether it’s already been answered. Please use the search box and you’ll find many questions about “not only but.” If none of those answers **your** question, then you can edit your post to explain what about your question differs from all those others.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum is correct. You could also improve your question by [edit]ing it to tell us what you think the difference is and why you're unsure about one or the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is not only but also used correctly in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298957/is-not-only-but-also-used-correctly-in-this-sentence)